# Rubyで文字列の式展開を後から行うには?

Tags: ruby

例えば、なんらかの名前を受け取り、その名前に対して挨拶するようなクラスとして、以下のようなものを定義したとします。

```
 class SimpleGreeting
   def initialize name
     @name = name
   end

   def say
     "Hello, #{@name}"
   end
 end
```

このとき、`say`の内部にある文字列を変えることができれば、もっと柔軟な挨拶ができるのではないか、と思いました。しかし、最初に文字列を渡して、あとから式展開を行うスマートな方法がわかりません。それに近い挙動は再現できたのですが、とてもスマートとはいえない気がします。

```
 class Greeting
   def initialize name, template
     @name = name
     @template = "\"#{template}\""
   end

   def say
     eval <<-EOF
 name = '#{@name}'
 #{@template}
     EOF
   end
 end
```

このようなクラスを定義してあげれば、確かに下のように利用することは可能です。

```
 puts Greeting.new('esehara', 'Hello, #{name}').say
 #output: Hello, esehara
 puts Greeting.new('esehara', 'こんにちは, #{name}').say
 #output: こんにちは, esehara
```

とはいえ、このような挙動を、もっと簡単に実現する方法がありそうな気がしましたが、どうでしょうか。それとも、このような文字列の使い方そのものが余りスマートではないと考えるべきなのでしょうか?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

initialize にブロックを渡すのがスマートかなと思います。

```
class Greeting
  def initialize(name, &block)
    @name = name
    @block = block
  end

  def say
    @block.call(@name)
  end
end

puts Greeting.new("Fate") { |name| "Hello, #{name}" }.say
puts Greeting.new("フェイトちゃん") { |name| "こんにちは, #{name}" }.say
```

結果:

```
Hello, Fate
こんにちは, フェイトちゃん
```

attr_accessor を定義すると、さらに汎用的に使えそうです。

Answer (score 5):

敢えて `eval` を使いつつスッキリさせるならば、式中に`{}`を含められない制限はできてしまいますが、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
class Greeding
  def initialize name, template
    @name = name
    @template = template
  end

  def say
    @template.gsub(/#\{([^}]*)\}/) { eval($1).to_s }
  end
end
```

文字列中の `#{EXPR}` を正規表現で抜き出して `eval(EXPR).to_s` の結果に置き換えています。

ただしその例のように単に変数を参照するだけならば [Kernel#format](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/Kernel.html#M_FORMAT) を使って、`say` メソッドは以下のように書き換えて、与えるテンプレートを `'Hello, %{name}'` のように変えてしまうのも良いのではないでしょうか。

```
def say
  @template % { name: @name }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

文字列の式展開は式が書かれた場所で文字列が展開することを意図して使ったほうが混乱が少ないと思います。

値の展開を後から行うという目的には `ERB` という値を後から組み込んで展開するためのライブラリが標準で準備されています。

- http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/ERB.html
- http://magazine.rubyist.net/?0017-BundledLibraries

これを使いましょう。

```
require 'erb'

class Greeting
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def say(template = 'Hello, <%= @name %>')
    ERB.new(template).result(binding)
  end
end


if __FILE__ == $0 then
  g = Greeting.new('似非原')
  puts g.say
  puts g.say('こんにちは <%= @name %>')
end
```

テンプレートエンジンのようにいくつかの文字列に特殊な意味がありますので、それに留意が必要ですが、後から文字列を展開したいという目的に対して自然な表現ができます。

Answer (score 3):

Koronさんの回答に補足ですが、`String`クラスの`%`メソッドは`Kernel.sprintf`の第一引数に文字列自身を渡した場合と同じ挙動になります。（Rubyでは`%`演算子は`%`メソッドの呼び出しを意味します）。

```
'Hello, %s' % 'John' #=> "Hello, John"
sprintf('Hello, %s' , 'John') #=> "Hello, John"
```

もし、実行時にテンプレートと文字列を合成したいのであれば、`%`メソッドを使うのが一番シンプルかと思います。

`sprintf`メソッドの挙動については公式ドキュメントを参照ください（C言語のsprintfと同じです）。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/print_format.html

Answer (score 2):

templateの適用部分は @KoRoNさんの回答を参考にされるといいと思うのですが、

templateをコンストラクタに渡すよりは別のリソースから取得できる方が柔軟性は高くなるように思います。
たとえば国際化対応ではテンプレート部分は外部ファイルから取得することが多いです。

Comment: 国際化対応という意味では [ruby-gettext](http://ruby-gettext.github.io/) とかのフレームワークに頼るのが良さそうですね。

Comment: @KoRoN そうですね、実際の国際化では自分で実装するよりフレームワークを使う方が得策ですね。

Answer (score 2):

そのままevalで、以下ではどうでしょうか。

```
class Greeting
   def initialize(name, template)
     @name = name
     @template = template
   end

   def say
     name = @name
     eval("<<XXX\n" + @template + "\nXXX\n") # XXXは適当に決める
   end
end

puts Greeting.new('esehara', 'Hello, #{name}').say
puts Greeting.new('esehara', 'Hello, #{@name}').say
```

以前、外部設定ファイルの一行を実行時展開したくなり、一行だけの展開だと
ERBを持ってきたり展開用のクラスを入れるのは大げさすぎるので上に落ち着きました。
テンプレートに入る文字列をある程度制限できるなら上で足りるかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1610/2599 の回答とほぼ同じです。

最初に文字列を渡して、あとから式展開を行うためには、文字列自体の評価を遅延させるとよさそうです。
文字列をブロックで囲うとブロックが呼び出されるまで文字列の評価を遅延させることができます。

ブロックを評価する際に[BasicObject#instance_eval](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/BasicObject/i/instance_eval.html)や[BasicObject#instance_exec](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/BasicObject/i/instance_exec.html)を使えば、`Greeting`オブジェクト自身のコンテキストでブロックを実行することができます。

`instance_eval`や`instance_exec`を使うことにより、文字列の式展開中からGreetingオブジェクトのインスタンス変数やインスタンスメソッドに自由にアクセスできるようになります。

```rb
class Greeting
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name, &template)
    @name = name
    @template = template
  end

  def say
    instance_eval(&@template)
  end
end

# ブロックがGreetingオブジェクトのコンテキストで評価されるのでインスタンス変数に自由にアクセスできる
Greeting.new('世界') { "こんにちは, #{@name}" }.say
# => "こんにちは, 世界"

# Greetingオブジェクトがselfになるのでnameメソッドが呼べる
Greeting.new('世界') { "こんにちは, #{name}" }.say
# => "こんにちは, 世界"
```